# how to iterate over object and dynamically assign values to keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hella all,

so I am struggling with the following problem:
I have an object with some keys and values. I would like to take them out and make a new array of objects. Here is the code, as it describes my problem better.

```js
const sourceObj = {
  test1: "a",
  test2: "b",
  test3: "c",
  test4: "d",
  test5: "e"
};

const myTable = [];

for (let value of sourceObj) {
  for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    const targetObject = {
      foo: "foo",
      year: value.test + i,
      bar: "bar"
    };
    myTable.push(targetObject);
  }
}

console.log(myTable);

// expected output
// [
//   {
//     foo: "foo",
//     year: "a",
//     bar: "bar"
//   },
//   {
//     foo: "foo",
//     year: "b",
//     bar: "bar"
//   },
//   ...
//   {
//     foo: "foo",
//     year: "e",
//     bar: "bar"
//   },
// ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can iterate on object keys and use method array.map to get the expected object

```js
const sourceObj = {
  test1: "a",
  test2: "b",
  test3: "c",
  test4: "d",
  test5: "e"
};

const myTable = Object.keys(sourceObj).map((key) => {
  return {
      foo: "foo",
      year: sourceObj[key],
      bar: "bar"
    };
});

console.log(myTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Object.values` and map over it

```js
const sourceObj = {
  test1: "a",
  test2: "b",
  test3: "c",
  test4: "d",
  test5: "e"
};

const myTable = Object.values(sourceObj).map(year => ({
  foo: "foo",
  year,
  bar: "bar"
}))
console.log(myTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const sourceObj = {
  test1: "a",
  test2: "b",
  test3: "c",
  test4: "d",
  test5: "e"
};

const myTable = [];

for(item in sourceObj){
  myTable.push(
    {
      foo : "foo",
      year : sourceObj[item],
      bar : "bar"
    }
  );
}

console.log(myTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let myTable = Object.values(sourceObj).map((element) => ({
    foo: "foo",
    year: element,
    bar: "bar"
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement

The `for...in` statement iterates over all [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.

```js
const sourceObj = {
  test1: "a",
  test2: "b",
  test3: "c",
  test4: "d",
  test5: "e"
};

const myTable = [];

for (let key in sourceObj) {
    const targetObject = {
      foo: "foo",
      year: sourceObj[key],
      bar: "bar"
    };
    myTable.push(targetObject);
}

console.log(myTable);
```